# Create one bean for each enum value with Spring annotations

Tags: java, spring

Is there an elegant way to create multiple bean instances of the same type, each parameterized according to an enum value? For example:

```
//MyEnum.java
enum MyEnum
{
 VALUE1,
 VALUE2;
}

//MyClass.java
class MyClass
{
  MyClass(MyEnum myEnum){ ... }
}

//Context.java
@Configuration
class Configuration
{
  @Bean
  public MyClass myClass1()
  {
    return new MyClass(MyEnum.VALUE1);
  }

  @Bean
  public MyClass myClass2()
  {
    return new MyClass(MyEnum.VALUE2);
  }
}
```

Is there a better way than explicitly creating a new bean for each enum value? Note that the names of the beans do not really matter, since I'll be searching from them using getBeanNamesForType(MyClass.class) later.

Comment: I'm just curious, what's the use case for needing to have Spring manage your enums?

Comment: The enums are just a detail. What I really want is for Spring to instantiate a whole family of beans, each constructed with a slightly different set of parameters. A sort of "cartesian product" over one or more parameter axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate answering my own question. I was able to do achieve what I wanted using DefaultListableBeanFactory.

```
@Bean
public ApplicationContextAware pseudoFactory()
{
return new ApplicationContextAware()
  {
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext( ApplicationContext ac )
    {
      GenericApplicationContext gac = (GenericApplicationContext) ac;

      DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) gac.getBeanFactory();

      for( EnumType enumType : EnumType.values())
      {
        ParameterizedClass pc = new ParameterizedClass(enumType);

        String beanName = enumType.getName() + "ParameterizedClass";

        beanFactory.registerSingleton(beanName, pc);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to return a `List<MyEnum>`:

```
@Bean
public List<MyEnum> myEnums() {
    return Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values());
}
```

You can't use `@Autowired` to inject, but `@Resource` works as long as you do it by name (more information on this in the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)):

```
@Resource(name = "myEnums") List<MyEnum> enumValues;
```

You could obviously use this same approach for any list of beans.